# Remove charges from app store and make app free download for all users and add charges in some specific features of app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

App is live and its charges when user download app from app. now, my requirement is that make it free for all user(not chargeable at downloading time) and make it chargeable for access some specific feature of app. I have used app in purchase Non-Renewing Subscription type. can any one suggest how to do that. any suggestion is appreciated. and thanks in advance.

regards
kaushal

Answer (score 1):

You need to set pricing 0 in price schedule https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/1137358828/pricing[enter link description here](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/1137358828/pricing)

[image]

Comment: many thanks @Jogendar . it reflect on next update or from current live build ??

Comment: NO need to wait for next update, it will reflect in some time

Comment: @KaushalKumar: If you fine with my answer then please accept my answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: and make it chargeable for user on access some specific feature of app.  how it will manage ??

Comment: @KaushalKumar You have to use In-app purchase for that